# recover data from raid 1 disk after "mdadm --create"

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have disk that was part of raid 1. I created (probably mistakenly) new raid with that disk to recover the data:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --auto md --level=1 --force --raid-devices=1 /dev/sdc1
```

now mount says:

```
~$ mount -t auto /dev/md0 /mnt/test/
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/md0': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/md0' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

It looks like "mdadm --create" has removed the information that sdc1 is/was ext4 file system.

Is the ext4 destroyed now? Can I somehow rescue it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `mdadm` does when asked to create a one-disk mirror.  You may still be able to recover the data: if it assumes the disk is clean, it'll have left most of the data alone, only wiping out things like the old headers.  You can use [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to go looking for backup copies of the filesystem superblock and reconstruct the partition.

If `mdadm` decided to do a resync, I hope you've got a backup.

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you. Incredible, TestDisk did the magic. It identified corrupt 'Invalid RAID superblock'  and  rescued ext4 partition with all the data. What I did before was also "mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdc" and "mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdc1" but I can't say if it was relevant.